# How to add external file outside the application folder to clickonce deployment (winappliction.net)

Tags: c#

I need to add any file type as like as (*.txt,*.jpg,*.prn,....)

I can include this files from external folder to my project

My first point is,rename this file and import to current project then include this,
after publish and run application rename any changed extension to original external.
but this is very chip!

---

the answer is here,

[Adding Files to a Click Once Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment)

tanx,best regards.

Comment: Try adding them as application resources, the clickonce installer should deploy them as well.

Comment: tanx,but after install i want this file existing in startup path and can access it.with this you say can,t it.