# Embed SQL .BAK file with WPF Clickonce Deployment

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

In the first installation in my WPF application I checked if the SQL database for my application exist or not, If not the application restore it from .bak SQL file.

When I publish my application I can't attach (Embed) the .bak file.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Abdusalam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well .. I got the solution :

One good way of doing this is:

- Create a folder under the app in VS name e.g. "datafiles"
- Add all files to that folder using Add as link in the dialog box after selecting Add existing item on the folder
- Mark all files as Copy if newer (Copy to output directory property)
- Make sure the build action is content
  --> when you publish the files will be put in that folder and be a part of the application installation

Good luck!

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment)