# Access denied Error in restoring SQL Server database WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2012, database-restore

In my application if the application installed for the first time on client machine, the application will restore there database if the database dose not exsist .. I included the .bak database according [This artical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment)  :

- Create a folder under the app in VS name e.g. "datafiles"
- Add all files to that folder using Add as link in the dialog box after selecting Add existing item on the folder
- Mark all files as Copy if newer (Copy to output directory property)
- Make sure the build action is content

when I publish the files put in publish folder and be a part of the application installation

Until now every thing work fine..

The probelm is when I trieng to restore the database from my code, the VS say :

> "Cannot open backup device, Operating system error 5 (Access is denied.)."

I tried to run the VS as administrator but this does not make any change..

Please can any one help me to solve this issue

Thanks in advance

Abdusalam

Comment: Is the problem when SQL Server is trying restore the database? If so, move the `.bak` file to the default SQL Server backup directory, and then try to restore the back up.

Comment: Yes, the problem happen in the restore step and the error message "Can not open .bak file, access denied", I need to include the .bak file with WPF click-once deployment for installation !