# Adding File to ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a .dat file that I need to call in my program. It runs fine, but if I publish the program or run it outside of the program it cannot use or find this file. Can anyone tell me the steps to use to attatch and call any file type for a click once application. I am trying to use the StreamReader if that helps at all.

Comment: Seems like this might solve your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940025/adding-files-to-a-click-once-deployment

Comment: Are you trying to attach a file at build/package time to the ClickOnce installation or are you trying to read a file after a program has been installed by ClickOnce?